# Is there any way to show table content like grid without scroll

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want show checkbox as a grid without scrolling the page. I am developing a attendance reporting page which shows student name and checkbox with values from database. I want to show its in a grid like this:

[image: this]

My code shows like this:

[image: this]

My code:

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="5" summary="">
<?php 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){?>
    <th>
      <input type="checkbox" class="input" id="input
         <?php echo $row['st_id']; ?>"
         name="student[]" value="<?php echo $row['st_id']; ?>" 
         checked="checked"   >
         <?php echo $row['st_name'] ; ?>
         <label for="input<?php echo $row['st_id']; ?>">
         </label>
    </th>
```

This code take both name and checkbox id from the database..Anybody please help

Comment: You could try using Bootstrap

Comment: can i put loop that automatically put <tr> tag after some count of <th>

Comment: Yes you can. [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/5sm64ts3/1/)\

Comment: Try my code. It automatically put <tr> tag after some count $counter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use floating DIVs instead of table:

```
    <style>
        .inputDiv{
            float: left;
            padding: 5px;
            margin: 5px;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
    <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) { ?>
        <div class="inputDiv">
            <input type="checkbox" class="input" id="input<?php echo $row['st_id']; ?>"  name="student[]" value="<?php echo $row['st_id']; ?>" checked="checked"   > <?php echo $row['st_name']; ?> 
            <label for="input<?php echo $row['st_id']; ?>"></label>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

This will reorder automatically all DIVs depending of user's screen resolution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it like this:

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="5" summary="">
<?php 
$counter = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
    if($number==1 ) {
        echo '<tr>';
    } 
    if($number %6 == 0) {
        echo '</tr><tr>';   
    }
?>
<th> <input type="checkbox" class="input" id="input<?php echo $row['st_id']; ?>"  name="student[]" value="<?php echo $row['st_id']; ?>" checked="checked"   > <?php echo $row['st_name'] ; ?> <label for="input<?php echo $row['st_id']; ?>"></label></th>
<?php 
$counter++;
if($number==0 || $number %6 == 0) {
        echo '</tr>';
    } 
}
?>
</tr>
</table>
```